# Read the Message only countable number of times in Spring AMQP

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am having an application which receives the message from RabbitMQ. Once the message is consumed and if it encounters some issue. I have set the `setDefaultRequeueRejected` to `true` and it is re queuing back.

Now i have scenario, If the message goes back to the queue, again it will be consumed and again re-queues. This has form a kind of cycle.

Now i need to consume the re-queued message only twice (Maintaining kind of a counter) and after that i will push it to ErrorQueue/DeadLetter Queue.
**How to maintain such counter ?**

Regards,

Chandan

Answer (score 0):

RabbitMQ doesn't provide such a mechanism, just a boolean header that indicates the message was redelivered.

If the sender sets a messageId header, you can use a [stateful retry interceptor with](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#retry) and the framework will keep track of how many times the same message has been delivered. With a `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer`, the message will be sent to the DLQ (if configured) after retries are exhausted.

If you don't have message ids, you can use a custom `MessageKeyGenerator` to generate a key for the state from the message itself.

Comment: Thanks Gary. I am interested to more regarding `MessageKeyGenerator `. Could you please provide me some sample implementation/example. This will help me a lot :)

Comment: It's a simple interface `Object getKey(Message message)` you get a reference to the message and return a value that uniquely identifies the message (such as from a header, or the message body). If there is no generator, we use the `messageId` property - which should be set by the sender, and unique. The message is raw, before any conversion.

Comment: I still didn't get clarity. Could you please redirect me to some sample implementation ?

Comment: There are no samples - it's a very straightforward concept - there needs to be something in the message that uniquely identifies it. If you can't do that, you are out of luck. The simplest solution is to change the sender to set the `messageId` property with a unique value, such as UUID.randomUUID.toString()`. If the sender is a Spring AMQP application make sure the `createMessageIds` property is `true` in the RabbitTemplate's message converter and there will be a unique message id in each message.

Comment: Yes i got this. But each time when consumer consumes the message, how can i maintain a counter like i am getting this message for second time so i will throw it off?

Comment: See the documentation I pointed you too - the retry interceptor takes care of all that. After the retries are exhausted, the recoverer takes over. By default, it is simply logged; a `RejectAndDontRequeueRecoverer` will cause the message to be rejected and not requeued (can go to a dead-letter queue if so configured) or the `RepublishMessageRecoverer` will write the failed message to another queue.